# React componente ,falla en logica | no se cual es el error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, hook

(los imports no lo subo porque estan esta bien)
Yo pienso que el problema está en `useStock` con los `if` no cambia el estado del size, siempre permanece en el S que lo inicie como el valor inicial.

Cuando hago `console.log` en el mismo componente de `useSize` cambian los valores de *S* a *M* o *L*, pero al pasar el size como `customHook`, no funciona

```
    export const useSize = () => {
    
    
    const [ size, setSize ] = useState('S')
 
    
    const s = () => setSize('S')
    const m = () => setSize('M')
    const l = () => setSize('L')
    
    console.log(size)
    return {
        s,m,l,
        size 
    }
    }
```

```
    export const ItemSize = ( {item} ) => {

    const { s, m , l } = useSize()
 
    return (
        <>
            {
                (item.stock === 0) ?
                ''
                :
                <> 
                        <label htmlFor="sort-by" className="sort_by"> TALLE </label>
                        <select id="sort-by">
                            <option 
                            onClick={ s }
                            >S
                            </option>

                            <option
                            onClick={ m }
                            >M
                            </option>

                            <option
                            onClick={ l }
                            >L
                            </option>        
                        </select>
               </>        
            }
      </>
    )
 }
```

```
export const useStock = () => {

    const [ stock, setStock ] = useState()
    const { itemId } = useParams()
    const { size } = useSize()
    
    const docRef = doc(db , 'productos', itemId)
    
    if (size === 'L') {
        getDoc(docRef)
        .then((doc) => {
            const newItem = { id:doc.id, ...doc.data()}
            setStock(newItem.stock.l)
        })
        
    } else if (size === 'M') {
        getDoc(docRef)
        .then((doc) => {
            const newItem = { id:doc.id, ...doc.data()}
            setStock(newItem.stock.m)
        })
        
    } else if (size === 'S') {
        getDoc(docRef)
        .then((doc) => {
            const newItem = { id:doc.id, ...doc.data()}
            setStock(newItem.stock.s)   
        })
    }
    console.log(size)
        
    return ({stock})
}
```

Comment: El problema está en el select, que al seleccionar una opción no salta el evento onClick, para saber cual se selecciona tendrías que usar el onChange en el elemento select

Comment: Gracias Suso pero no funciono. Tenias razon igual pero sigue sin cambiar :(

Answer (score 0):

como te he dicho el problema está en el select, en el que hay que usar el evento onChange, lo malo es ejecutar una función dependiendo de un string es un poco complicado.

```
function handleChangeSize(){
    if(value === "s") s();
    else if(value === "m") m();
    else l();
}

<select id="sort-by" onChange={handleChangeSize} value={size}>
       <option value="S">S</option>
       <option value="M" >M</option>
       <option value="L">L</option> 
</select>
```

Yo en el hook que creaste en lugar de hacer tres funciones, una para cada talla es mejor usar 1 que reciba el valor. Parece mas simple, aunque al final te quedaría como un hook normal de react. He añadido un array allowedSizes para controlar las tallas que se introducen, aunque haciendolo desde un select con el onchange, no debería de hacer falta.

```
const useSize = () =>{
   const [size, setSize] = useState("S")

   const allowedSizes = ["S", "M", "L"];

   const updateSize = (value) =>{
      if(allowedSizes.includes(value)){
         setSize(value.toUpperCase());
      }
   }

   return { size, updateSize, allowedSizes}
}
```

y en el handleChange:

```
function handleChangeSize(e){
  const value = e.target.value;
  updateSize(value);
}
```

De esta manera, con el array de allowedSizes tambien podrías renderizar dinamicamente las opciones:

```
<select id="sort-by" onChange={handleChangeSize} value={size}>
       {allowedSizes.map((x,index)=>{
             return <option key={index} value={x}>{x}</option>})}      
</select>
```

Comment: Hola Suso, si  de casualidad lo lees, todavia no termine de hacer los cambios que ofreciste pero logre resolverlo juntando todo ya que es para una entrega
Lo que si tome fue el handleSize, mas logico una funcion a 3
Pero no termine de hacer todas las correcciones. Desde ya te agradezco igual
Tenia otra consulta si de casualidad podias responderla, como hago para pasar  de un comonente a otro, no por parametro y context no funcionaria porque se modifica constantemente, seria el estado size. 
Veras, cada producto tiene su propio size, y no se como individualizar y compartir dicho estado.
TY

Comment: Pues la verdad así sin código y sin saber nada mas pues no estoy seguro. Hacia arriba no podrás compartir a no ser que sea un contexto que englobe todo o redux o el local storage. hacia abajo pues por parámetros y por los anteriores. Otra manera es usando el document.getElementbyId pero yo en react practicamente no lo uso